# Batch error on REST api with Neo4j 2.1.1

Tags: neo4j

On a Debian wheezy instance I've just migrated my standalone Neo4j server from version 2.0.2 to 2.1.1 (I run on java-7-openjdk-amd64.). Since I'm experiencing problems with batch queries on REST api :

On a empty database I tried the following test :

- First I created a node :

  ```
  curl -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -X POST -d '{"name":"Steven"}' http://localhost:7474/db/data/node
  ```

the node was created successfully :

```
    {
      "extensions" : {
      },
      "paged_traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
      "labels" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/labels",
      "outgoing_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out",
      "traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/traverse/{returnType}",
      "all_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
      "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties/{key}",
      "all_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all",
      "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0",
      "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
      "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties",
      "incoming_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in",
      "incoming_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
      "create_relationship" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships",
      "data" : {
        "name" : "Steven"
    }
```

- then I tried to get the new node :

  ```
  curl -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -X GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0
  ```

which gave me the expected result :

```
    {
      "extensions" : {
      },
      "paged_traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
      "labels" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/labels",
      "outgoing_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out",
      "traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/traverse/{returnType}",
      "all_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
      "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties/{key}",
      "all_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all",
      "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0",
      "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
      "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties",
      "incoming_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in",
      "incoming_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
      "create_relationship" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships",
      "data" : {
        "name" : "Steven"
    }
```

- but the same request in a batch gave me the following error

  ```
  curl -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -X POST -d '[{"method":"GET","to":"/node/0","id":0}]' http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch

  {
    "exception" : "NullPointerException",
    "fullname" : "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.invokeDirectly(Jetty9WebServer.java:339)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.invoke(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:55)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.performRequest(BatchOperations.java:201)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.parseAndPerform(BatchOperations.java:171)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.performBatchJobs(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:48)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.batchProcess(BatchOperationService.java:126)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.performBatchOperations(BatchOperationService.java:76)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)"]
  ```

The only log I saw was the http ones :

127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:14:56:17 +0200] "POST /db/data/node HTTP/1.1" 201 1160 "-" "curl/7.26.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:14:56:33 +0200] "GET /db/data/node/0 HTTP/1.1" 200 1160 "-" "curl/7.26.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2014:14:56:47 +0200] "POST /db/data/batch HTTP/1.1" 500 1000 "-" "curl/7.26.0"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

*Edit*: The exact same request in streaming mode (i.e. with header X-Stream set to true) has a different behavior : it gives the expected data but with a status 500.

```
curl -H X-Stream:true -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -X POST -d '[{"method":"GET","to":"/node/0","id":0}]' http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch

[
  {
    "id":0,
    "from":"/node/0",
    "body":
      {
        "extensions":{},
        "paged_traverse":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
        "labels":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/labels",
        "outgoing_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out",
        "traverse":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/traverse/{returnType}",
        "all_typed_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
        "property":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties/{key}",
        "all_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all",
        "self":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0",
        "properties":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties",
        "outgoing_typed_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
        "incoming_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in",
        "incoming_typed_relationships":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
        "create_relationship":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships",
        "data":
          {
            "name":"Steven"
          }
      },
    "status":500
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm working with @benito-de-la-casita and the exact same request works on Neo4J 2.1.1, installed via Homebrew on MacOS X Mavericks

Comment: A proper issue has been created for this : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2517